# Use Github Desktop to work on branch on my computer

Tags: git, github, github-desktop

I am running Github Desktop on my Mac and I want to create a branch of a github repository and work on it on my Mac. I can see how to create a branch in Github Desktop but not how to download the branch to my Mac so I can work on it and subsequently commit changes to the branch.

Comment: Did you clone from GitHub? `clone` is how you get a remote repository to your local machine and would be the first thing to do if you want to work on a project that is on GitHub.

Comment: Do I have to do this in GitHub rather than GitHub Desktop?

Comment: You may want to [follow a tutorial](https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1) or [read the Git Book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) to better understand git (if you don't know how to answer the question "have you cloned yet?").

Comment: I can't find any documentation that describes how to do this with Github Desktop (hence the reason for the question). I can see how to do it in Github though.

Comment: You can create the branch locally *after* you have cloned the repository (get a local copy), *or* you can create the branch on GitHub and get it when you initially `clone` (if you have not already) or subsequently `fetch` (after you have a clone). There is documentation for doing all of these things with GitHub Desktop.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot find the documentation for how to create a branch and clone in Github Desktop.

Comment: [google github desktop clone](https://www.google.com/search?q=github%20desktop%20clone) and [google github desktop branch](https://www.google.com/search?q=github%20desktop%20clone#q=github+desktop+branch&*)?

Comment: Sorry I should have said that when I could not find any documentation I had tried googling this. I only ever ask questions on Stackoverflow when I have exhausted all of my searches. I am here because I have failed to find the information I need. I have created a branch on GitHub but cannot find anywhere that tells me how to use GitHub Desktop to attach to the branch and clone it on my desktop.